Solve the equation $|4x-3|+ |4x+3|=6$
problem
Solve the equation $|4x-3|+ |4x+3|=6$
my idea
First we wrote $|4x-3|+ |4x+3|= |-4x+3|+ |4x+3|$ and used the triangle inequality ($|a|+|b| \geq |a+ b|$ with equality only when both a and b are positive or negative at the same time) and we obtained that $|4x-3|+ |4x+3|= |-4x+3|+ |4x +3| \geq 6$ with equality when $-4x+3, 4x+3 \geq 0$ which means that $x \in [\frac{-3}{4}, \frac{3}{4}]$ or when $-4x+3, 4x+3 \leq 0$ which was no solution.
I'm not sure if I did correctly when I applied the case of equality. Should I take both cases when $\geq 0$ and when $<0$?

Compare with similar computations, e.g., here, or here, or here, or here.

There are three cases to deal with: $x \le -\frac{3}{4}$, $-\frac{3}{4} \le x \le \frac{3}{4}$, and $x \ge \frac{3}{4}$.

@DietrichBurde Thanks. But i see none of the sources use my idea, I'm interested in knowing if my idea is correct...

As it is a strict equality, using an inequality will not be precise enough and add a lot more cases.  Just do it.  There are four cases $|4x-3| = \pm (4x-3)$ and $|4x+3|=6$ so just solve $\pm (4x-3) + (\pm (4x+3)) = 6$.  (then check for  those that $\pm(4x-3)$ and $\pm(4x+3)$ are non negative.

@fleablood Yeah, but the inequality also says that the cases of equality occurs when both have the same sign...doesn't it make a correct solution?

OP: Hi! I removed the modules tag because as far as I can tell, it's not relevant. Did you read the tag description?

Your solution looks valid to me, and I like it. If this were a problem in a precalculus course, I'd expect solutions more like the answers below.

Your solution is original and smart indeed. Where precisely is your doubt? Is it about strict or large inequality in the second case?

You have posted a very similar question at the same time. Take time to breath...

@JeanMarie These two questions are not "very similar". In each, the OP asked for a feedback on their method, which is really different. The method in the linked post is much more standard.

Despite my doubts your way does work.
If $(-4x+3)$ and $(4x+3)$ are the same sign we get
$|(-4x+3)+(4x+3)| = |(-4x+3)|+|4x+3| = 6$ and as $|(-4x+3) + (4x+3)| = |6|=6$ this is certain always true if $-4x+3$ and $4x+3$ are the same sign.
If $(-4x+3)$ and $(4x+3)$ are opposite signs we get $|(-4x+3)+(4x+3)|> |-4x+3| + |4x+3| = 6$ but as $|(-4x+3) + (4x+3)| = |6|=6$ this can never be true.
So it is true if either $-4x + 3\ge 0$ and $4x+3 \ge 0$ or if $-4x+3 < 0$ and $4x+3 < 0$.  There former is $x\in [-\frac 34,\frac 34]$ and the latter is contradictory.  Hence your solution.
But in my opinion this is overkill.
For one thing in real numbers the triangle inequality is can be much more strongly stated that as $|A+B| = \begin{cases} \max(|A|,|B|)-\min(|A|,|B|)&\text{which is }\le |A|+|B|\\|A|+|B|\end{cases}$.
and it'd be easier to do it in cases and
This is a case the $x$s "cancel out".  I don't think another case, such as $|4x+3| + |3x-4| = 7$ would work as nice.
(Let's see.  Either $|4x+3 +(-3x+4)|=|x+7|=7$ and $-\frac 34 \le x \le \frac 43$ and $x=\pm 7$. Impossible. so $|4x+3+(-3x+4)|=|x+7|> 7$ while $4x+3$ and $-3x+4$ or opposite signs.  In this case we have an inequality that will not give a precise answer.)
